# How to calculate pseudo R-squared from a model fitted with gls from the nlme package in R

Tags: r

I used gls from nlme to fit this model:

```
require(nlme)

set.seed(101)
mp <-data.frame(year=1990:2010)
N <- nrow(mp)

mp <- within(mp,
     {
         wav <- rnorm(N)*cos(2*pi*year)+rnorm(N)*sin(2*pi*year)+5
         wow <- rnorm(N)*wav+rnorm(N)*wav^3
     })

m01 <- gls(wow~poly(wav,3), data=mp, correlation = corARMA(p=1))
```

I would like to calculate any measure of goodness of fit like a pseudo R-squared: which one could be recommended? and how to calculate it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here there are some pseudo R-squared

```
R2 <- cor(mp$wow,predict(m01))^2

R2

R2.1 <- 1 - with(mp, (sum((wow-predict(m01))^2)/sum((wow-mean(wow))^2)))

R2.1
```

The McFadden pseudo R2

```
m00 <- gls(wow~1, data=mp, correlation = corARMA(p=1))

R2.n <- 1-(as.numeric(logLik(m01)/logLik(m00)))

R2.n
```

but I don't which one is better to asses the goodness of fit for this kind of model.

Comment: Hi, [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/Psuedo_RSquareds.htm) there are some more pseudo R2 and their interpretation. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You need to have some sort of baseline for comparison:

```
> summary(m01)
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: wow ~ poly(wav, 3) 
  Data: mp 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  226.5434 231.5427 -107.2717

 m01 <- gls(wow~1, data=mp, correlation = corARMA(p=1))
> summary(m01)
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: wow ~ 1 
  Data: mp 
       AIC     BIC    logLik
  256.5048 259.492 -125.2524
```

The problem with nonlinear fits is that the mean value is no longer a "baseline" and that is what an R-square  measure assumes.

Comment: Does this mean, that the answer of @Leosar using the model `m00 <- gls(wow~1, data=mp, correlation = corARMA(p=1))`as a baseline is a sensible approach to calculate McFaddens pseudo-R²?

Comment: I suspect not. I suspect that neither he nor I can answer that question with solid statistical arguments. I do know that linear mixed models do NOT have an easy to interpret GOF approach: see this Q&A https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37944/what-are-easy-to-interpret-goodness-of-fit-measures-for-linear-mixed-effects-mo

Comment: On the other hand when you look at `?rcompanion::naglekerke` (suggested by another respondent) it appears these class of models are considered fair game with all the caveats on that help page, in particular the ones about not considering them real GOF results and  "The fitted model and the null model should be properly nested. That is, the terms of one need to be a subset of the the other, and they should have the same set of observations." Since @Leosar's example does qualify as nested, perhaps it qualifies.

Answer (score 3):

`rcompanion::nagelkerke ()` computes three different pseudo-R² values. The function accepts models fitted via `nlme::gls`.

Answer (score 0):

`summary(m01)` should give you what you are looking for, assuming I understand your question correctly? `??fit` will provide you with further suggestions.

Comment: @DWin, good point. I guess `help.search("fit", package = "nlme")` should be used.